# Validate JSON with json schema is failing

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hi I need to do a school assigement with a API thats generating json.

I get with $API my json. With some testing by myself I can say that the json is correct. But in the assigement it says I need to validate it with a json schema. I have the schema but I cant get it to work so it will check and validate the incomming json.

If someone sees the problem pls tell me because I cant find it.

```
                <?php
                    //Json gets validated
                    if(isset($API))
                    {                   
                        ?>
                            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/validate.js/0.13.1/validate.min.js">
                            var validator = require('validator');
                            var jsv = require('json-validator');
                            jsv.validate("<?php echo $API; ?>", "json_schema.json", function(err, messages)) {
                                    if(err) 
                                    {
                                        throw err;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $.getJSON("<?php echo $API; ?>", function(data) 
                                        {
                                            var items = [];
                                            $.each(data, function(key, val, val2) {
                                                items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val["COL 3"] + "</li>");
                                                items.push("<br>");
                                            });

                                            $("<ul/>", {
                                                "class": "my-new-list",
                                                html: items.join("")
                                            }).appendTo(".datapanel");
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: What error do you get? I see you're injecting your JSON from the $API variable, is it correctly escaped to avoid issues with the `"`?

Comment: I dont think thats the issue, I dont get a error, its not doing anything. I check the if(isset($API), thats also not the problem because if I remove the validation it will work

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($API)` to show the content of `$API`?

Comment: [link](https://gyazo.com/9266e9369fce44c82c3ba3191a4ec0cf)
The link with the output

Comment: So yes, I think this is due to the `"` being unescaped. I'll write a proposition in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Replace both `<?php echo $API; ?>` by `<?php echo str_replace('"', '\\"', $API); ?>`.

Even better, you could have this process once and then echo the escaped string:

```php
<?php
    // Json gets validated
    if (isset($API))
    {
        // escape your JSON string
        $escapedAPI = str_replace('"', '\\"', $API);
        ?>

        ...

        <!-- echo the escaped string -->
        <?php echo $escapedAPI; ?>

        ...

        <?php
    }
?>
```

The issue you're facing is that currenty, when PHP echo the JSON in your Javascript, it produces something like this:

```js
jsv.validate("[{"COL 3":"(APPLAUSE)"}, ... ]", "json_schema.json", function() { ... })
```

As you can see, the `"` from the Javascript are mixed with the one "echoed" which produce invalid Javascript. This is why you need to escape them before "echoing" your JSON.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but unfortunately this is not the solution. The $API is a URL for the API to get the JSON. Idk if this was confusing